# ns_error_not_available quando posto no servidor web

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Eu fiz um mini jogo no localhost e estava tudo a funcionar perfeitamente.. Depois fiz o upload para o servidor web e o jogo começou a crashar com o erro "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:".

```
...
var spriteSheet = new Image();
var player = new Sprite(spriteSheet);sprites.push(player);
...
for (var i in sprites) {
    var spr = sprites[i];
    if (spr.visible) {
        spr.draw(ctx); // erro aqui
    }
}
...
```

(noutro ficheiro .js)

```
...
this.draw = function(ctx){
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.srcX, this.srcY, this.width, this.height,this.posX,this.posY, this.width, this.height); // erro aqui
        this.animation();
    } 
...
```

Estive a pesquisar sobre este assunto e penso que seja preciso criar uma função para carregar as imagens antes de inicializar o jogo em si.

Comment: Esse erro aparece no browser ou no servidor?

Comment: O erro aparece no browser